# LaTeX ToC not displaying previous chapters

Tags: tocstyle

I am writing a thesis and I cannot get my ToC to display itself or anything that appears before it in the document (i.e. my abstract comes before the ToC, but is not listed in the ToC!).

```
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}


\newpage

\tableofcontents\newpage

\listoffigures\newpage

\listoftables\newpage


\clearpage

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Welcome, please provide a fully compilable example. Here we have no idea which document class your are using or which packages. Did you remember to compile several times for the ToC to be generated?

Answer (score 2):

The star form of `\chapter` does not add an entry in the table of contents. This can be done via `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}


\newpage

\tableofcontents\newpage

\listoffigures\newpage

\listoftables\newpage


\clearpage

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Class `book`

Class `book` provides `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter`, which takes care of the page numbering style. Also `\frontmatter` lets its chapters unnumbered. Then `\chapter` without star can be used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{ABSTRACT}

\newpage

\tableofcontents\newpage

\listoffigures\newpage

\listoftables\newpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the `\newpage`s and the `\clearpage` actually do anything useful here?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's an explicit way of saying, the last page of `\tableofcontents`, ... is finished. It's not wrong, usually it can be omitted, but it depends on the circumstances (class, packages, context), whether it is necessary. The following material might not start a new page automatically.