# Place Table of contents on a different page and add previous sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I am creating my dissertation where the acknowledgments and abstract come before the toc, how do I add them to said toc?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can add entries to the toc with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}` or similarly. Without a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927), it is difficult to help you more concretely. Does the `latex3` tag have any relevance to the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX ToC not displaying previous chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266622/latex-toc-not-displaying-previous-chapters)